# How to create modular html code based on python

Tags: python, html

I have a question about making HTML code using Python. For work, I'm doing some Data analysis and I want to make a report in HTML, but I need to make it so that the HTML code changes based on every run of python so, how can I make Python code so that for example I can make a table get longer or shorter based on the output of Python?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple string and list manipulation.**

```
html = """<HTML>
<body>
    <h1>Attendance list</h1>
    <table>
        {0}
    </table>
</body>
</HTML>"""

items = [['Jason', 'Brown', 'Leeds', '40'], ['Sarah', 'Robinson', 'Bristol', '32'], ['Carlo', 'Baldi', 'Manchester', '41']]
tr = "<tr>{0}</tr>"
td = "<td>{0}</td>"
subitems = [tr.format(''.join([td.format(a) for a in item])) for item in items]
print (html.format("".join(subitems))) # or write, whichever
```

**Output:**

```
<HTML>
<body>
    <h1>Attendance list</h1>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Jason</td><td>Brown</td><td>Leeds</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>Sarah</td><td>Robinson</td><td>Bristol</td><td>32</td></tr><tr><td>Carlo</td><td>Baldi</td><td>Manchester</td><td>41</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</HTML>
```

**html output :**

[image: check it out here]

**Also for an alternative , you can do it using**  [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

```
from tabulate import tabulate

table = [['one','two','three'],['four','five','six'],['seven','eight','nine']]

print(tabulate(table, tablefmt='html'))
```

**Which produces the following output.**

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>one  </td><td>two  </td><td>three</td></tr>
<tr><td>four </td><td>five </td><td>six  </td></tr>
<tr><td>seven</td><td>eight</td><td>nine </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```